# Swift NSPredicate is returning all results rather than a single one

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I'm doing a very explicit search that should just return one result.

```
let pageFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Page")
let chapterPred = NSPredicate(format: "(chapter = %d)", Int(item.chapter)!)
let versePred   = NSPredicate(format: "(verse = %d)", Int(item.verse)!)
pageFetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .OrPredicateType, subpredicates: [chapterPred, versePred])
```

My `pageFetchRequest` will, for example, explicitly say :

```
<NSFetchRequest: 0x7fb4d2d09a60> (entity: Page; predicate: (chapter == 1 OR verse == 2); sortDescriptors: ((null)); type: NSManagedObjectResultType; )
```

There is only one result that matches this. But when I run :

```
do {
    var results:[NSManagedObject]
    results = try secondManagedContext.executeFetchRequest(pageFetchRequest) as! [Page]
```

`results` is all of my objects.

Here's a snapshot of my entity :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have verse = 2 in all your pages?
If you want verse = 2 in chapter 1 you should use:

```
pageFetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(type: .AndPredicateType, subpredicates: [chapterPred, versePred])
```